# How do I concatenate variables to a path in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, concatenation

Hello I was working on a project but I am stuck on concatenating two variable to a path for an ftp upload, So can you please help

```
import os
login=os.getlogin()
fname=str(filenum)+".txt"
fh = open(r"C:\Users\LOGIN HERE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\FNAME HERE", 'rb')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) should do the trick (although it's a bit of overkill here):

```
fh = open(os.path.join(r"C:\Users", login, "AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default", fname), 'rb')
```

Comment: but how do I input the variable login to this string?

Comment: @MattzManz missed that, sorry. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you it helps!